# Return 0 value if Details duplicated

Tags: crystal-reports

I need your help in creating crystal report.

I have a formula in details section that computes working time.

How do I make the value return 0 if it is duplicated?

Here's the scenario

Name Time (Hours:Minutes) 
John  1:20 
........     3:30 
........      3:30 
Total Hours -> ?

My problem is I dont want to use the duplicated values (3:30) like shown above. I want a total hours for 4:50.

Comment: didn't understood your requirement..  can you explain bit more?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function "previous" to compare the current value with the previous value, but it works only with fields.

But i am not sure if i understood, you may be more precise about your question.

1) make a formula called "hours" or some other name

```
 if not isnull(previous({Result.Time}) and {Result.Time} = previous({Result.Time}
 then 0
 else {Result.Time} /* you have to assure the same return type */
```

2) let the "total hours" be a sum of the formula "hours"

Note that it will work only if the rows are ordered by hours.

The result is the same of using a running total fields as purposed by Siva.

Answer (score 0):

you have two options:

1. check the option in `Database` tab.. `Select Distinct Records` so that duplicate records will be eliminated.
2. If you don't want to use the first option then to calculate use `Running Total` so that you sum only those that are distinct...

Create running total something like `Do sum only after change of time value`